# Nuxt prevent layout reload for evey page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am fetching data from an api when the layout loads (created). Because the data takes time and doesn't change, I want to load only once when creating the layout and put it in store. The problem is that calls to the api are made for every page navigation.

Is there a way to prevent layout from reloading (being created for every page)?

Answer (score 0):

if u dont want to fetch data everytime, you could use the store like this

in created hook where you want to fetch your data check if data is already stored or not ...

```
computed: mapState([
   'yourData'
]),
created(){
   if(!yourData){
      // now you can fetch everything you want 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it did not work. I resolved my issue using nuxtServerInit function is the store/index.js and also using nuxt-link as opposed to anchor tags. as shown in answer below

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using nuxtServerInit method in the store. I also replaced my anchor tags with nuxt-link

```
    //store/index.js
   ...
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    try {
      await this.$axios.get("regions/get-all", config).then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          commit("setRegions", res.data.regions);         
         
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }    
  },
```